# Valuation of discriminant

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, valuation-theory

So the discriminant of a polynomial of degree $n$ in the form of determinant of the resultant matrix can be written as

$$\det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C)$$

where $A, B, C, D$ are block matrices of the resultant matrix. $A$ is $(n-1)\times (n-1)$, $B$ is $(n-1)\times n$ and so on.

Now is it possible to find the valuation of $\det(A-BD^{-1}C)$ without explicitly calculating the discriminant?

Comment: What do you call the valuation of a matrix ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it is the valuation of the determinant.

Comment: Do you mean the absolute value of the determinant ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the valuation works on negatives.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand but I am surely stubborn ; for example what is the valuation of the following matrix : $\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\4&3 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie That isn't a thing. I'm talking about the valuation of the determinant of the matrix, and it has to depend on a $p$ value. The determinant is $-5$ so the valuation of the determinant is $0$ except when $p=5$.